# C malloc with string array

Tags: c, arrays, string, malloc

I am trying to make an array of strings by representing this array by a `char**`. However, I am getting a segmentation fault on this line:

```
char** values = malloc(count*sizeof(char*)+1); //+1 for terminating NUL
```

Any advice? `count` is a variable of type `size_t`. Thanks for any and all help!

Edit: Code before it:

```
size_t count = 0;
char** counter = params;
while(*counter) {
    count++;
    counter += sizeof(char*);
}
count++; //one space for NULL
char** values = malloc((count + 1) * sizeof(char*)); // +1 for terminating NULL
```

Comment: maybe be count * lenghtOfEachString, or i ask to you what is the sizeof(char*)?

Comment: Well later I reserve space at each `char*` in the array that this would create, but it doesn't even get to that line. It's an array of pointers to chars, so the string length doesn't matter at this line as long as the space for those chars are reserved elsewhere, which they are later.

Comment: but C can not handle that, you can create an array of pointer then create each one space on runtime otherwise you must give an maxlenght

Comment: Well isn't that what this is? I am trying to create this array of pointers that you say, but it is giving me a segfault.

Comment: count has a value of 3 when running it. I'm debugging it in Eclipse and it says that the segfault is firing at this line. I'm stepping through the code so it should pause after executing this line.

Comment: if next lines like `values[0] = malloc(10);` `values[0] = "asdasdasd";`musst be work fine. im tried

Comment: Exactly. It's quite confusing, especially since I run a line that is identical to it in another function that is called before this one without error.

Comment: Pointer arithmetic will do the multiplication for you. Don't `counter += sizeof(char*);`, just use `counter++;` to look at the next element.

Comment: `counter += sizeof(char*)` is a blunder. You're probably reading off into unallocated memory. You probably meant `++counter;` . Pointer arithmetic works in units of the thing being pointed to, not in bytes.

Comment: I will remedy that. However, the segfault is occurring on the malloc line, and the count is set to 3 when that line executes, as shown during debugging.

Comment: So I tried changing the line to `++counter` and it returns the incorrect number of elements

EDIT:

You were right. I forgot to change how the array was initialized previously. You answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Since `values` is an array of pointers, the code you are using is problematic. It should be:

```
char** values = malloc((count + 1) * sizeof(char*)); // +1 for terminating NULL
```

since you need `sizeof(char*)` bytes (and not `1` byte) for the terminating NULL. 
However, it is not clear that this line alone is causing the segfault... Maybe it is because of memory alignment issues (that arise because of the misplaced `+1` in the line you are using)...

Comment: Just tried it; no luck. That is the line causing it, because I am debugging it in Eclipse and when that line executes, the sigfault is fired.

Comment: What is the value of `count` that you are using?

Comment: `count` has a value of 3 when this line executes.